# Hive : get rows where difference between a date and date field is some value

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

This is my table 'ekko' and I need to get all rows where the difference between today's date and column aedat is greater than 65 days. How can I construct a hive query for the same? I use unix OS.

`id  rfid   aedat

---|-------|-------------|
1  | 3122  | 2017-12-08  |
2  | 3423  | 2017-12-27  |
3  | 4564  | 2017-11-09  |
4  | 23442 | 2017-10-03  |`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())` to get the current date.

```
select * from ekko where datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),aedat) > 65
```

or if your aedat is string type use the bellow one.

```
select * from ekko where datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),cast(aedat as date))>65;
```

Comment: It doesn't return any value.I guess that is because my aedat values are string type

Comment: In you table aedat, is a string or date, because if aedat is date type it will work.. ok.

Comment: aedat are string values.

Comment: then cast it to date. i have updated the answer do chk.. it will work

Answer (score 0):

In hive you can use **current_date** function which can have **today's date** i.e 2018-02-26 and then use **datediff function in where clause** to caluculate the **difference between aedat and current_date is greater than 65 days**.

With casting aedat as date type

```
hive>select * from ekko where datediff(current_date,cast(aedat as date))>65;
```

(or)

Without casting aedat to date type

```
hive> select * from ekko where datediff(current_date,aedat)>65;
```

Comment: My aedat values are string values.

Comment: Use the first query by cast aedat to date type
(or)
hive can even work with string types in datediff 
example:-

select datediff(current_date,'2017-12-23');

+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 65   |
+------+--+